# ReactNative doesn't respond to OrientationChanges

Tags: react-native, screen-orientation, expo

I'm trying to implement a navigation that pushes the user to a different screen when switching to landscape mode. I've tried for several hours now to implement an event listener to respond to an orientation change, which didn't work (I tried different examples from different websites).
Now, I took a full code example from  [here](https://tutorialscapital.com/dynamically-find-device-screen-orientation-portrait-or-landscape-react-native-tutorial/)  and [here](https://medium.com/@mridultripathi/effectively-change-orientation-in-react-native-and-detect-device-type-8b9f69d669d6)  which also didn't work at all. (The first one just changes the text on the screen depending on the orientation, even that didn't work for me -.- )

I also tried to look into ScreenOrientation from Expo-Cli directly (expo-screen-orientation), but don't really get the documentation tbh.

I tried the orientation change on both an android emulator and my android phone (both Android 10).

Is there something I'm terribly missing here? How come that my app not respond to orientation changes?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that the `Device Orientation` is not forced to `Portrait` in Xcode ? To check this go in Project -> General -> Device Orientation

Answer (score 0):

Had the Device Orientation locked inside the app.json -.-